# Could JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(foo)) alter a valid JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json

Assuming I have a **valid JSON string** (coming from a file or a database), could I consider that the data will not be altered if I run the command below? I don't care about indentation and other meaningless whitespaces: they could be stripped.

```js
const foo = someActuallyValidJSONString();

JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(foo));
```

Are order in array, null values, int/string, etc. preserved as-is?

*Precision: my actual goal is to remove one sub-property of a JSON from a database and send it back to the database without changing anything else.*

Comment: Why the detour database -> js -> database? o.O

Comment: Order in arrays is certainly preserved. Order of object properties may not be, but then there's no defined order in the first place. You _may_ see slight rounding of floats.

Comment: @Andreas Not all database system have nor have decent json support. Would not do it in Javascript either, but sometimes neither on the database.

Comment: @Andreas
> Why the detour database -> js -> database? o.O
Thank you for your question! That's because the JSON I want to update is complex (arrays in objects in arrays in objects...), and I would have to do call too much `jsonb_agg`, `jsonb_set`, `jsonb_build_object`, `jsonb_array_elements ` and so on (it may be possible though, I have done queries like this for other cases, but this one seems not a super candidate). I guess for my particular case, imperative programming (with loops and condition) is better over declarative programming. I would lose a bit of readability.

Comment: @JavaScript My database is PostgreSQL so I guess I could have done something. I use the right functions (`jsonb_*`) in all other places. But for my particular case, I prefer writing loops and conditions (JS) over a declarative (SQL) for readability and eloquence.

Comment: @deceze Thanks! Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @deceze (posted as a comment):

> Order in arrays is certainly preserved. Order of object properties may not be, but then there's no defined order in the first place. You may see slight rounding of floats